# How to configure the on your server spotlight to give the same output as the spotlight demo on the web?

Tags: java, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I am using the [run on your server spotlight](https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight#run-your-own-server). but couldn't configure the properties file so it will output the same output as the [demo](http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/demo/) does.

here is the demo screen shot shows the parameters it uses:
[image]

which are look like this (from the file `server.properties` which is locally on my machine):

```
org.dbpedia.spotlight.web.rest.uri = http://localhost:2222/rest
org.dbpedia.spotlight.index.dir = data/index 
org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.dictionary = data/spotter.dict 
jcs.default.cacheattributes.MaxObjects = 5000
org.dbpedia.spotlight.tagging.hmm = data/pos-en-general-brown.HiddenMarkovModel

org.dbpedia.spotlight.sparql.endpoint = http://dbpedia.org/sparql
org.dbpedia.spotlight.sparql.graph = http://dbpedia.org

# Configurations for the CoOccurrenceBasedSelector
# From: http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/download/release-0.5/spot_selector.tgz
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.cooccurrence.datasource = ukwac
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.cooccurrence.database.jdbcdriver = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.cooccurrence.database.connector = jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/spotsel/ukwac_candidate;shutdown=true&readonly=true
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.cooccurrence.database.user = sa
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.cooccurrence.database.password =
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.cooccurrence.classifier.unigram = data/spotsel/ukwac_unigram.model
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.cooccurrence.classifier.ngram = data/spotsel/ukwac_ngram.model

# Other possible values: AtLeastOneNounSelector,CoOccurrenceBasedSelector,NESpotter
org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.spotters = LingPipeSpotter

# org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.opennlp.dir = opennlp

# Info for context searcher
org.dbpedia.spotlight.language = English
org.dbpedia.spotlight.lucene.analyzer = SnowballAnalyzer

# Choose between jdbc or lucene for DBpedia Resource creation. Also, if the jdbc throws an error, lucene will be used.
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.core.database = jdbc
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.core.database.jdbcdriver = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.core.database.connector = jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/database/spotlight-db;shutdown=true&readonly=true
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.core.database.user = sa
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.core.database.password =

# List of disambiguators to load: Document,Occurrences,CuttingEdge,Default
org.dbpedia.spotlight.disambiguate.disambiguators = Default,Document


# From http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/download/release-0.5/candidate-index-full.tgz
# org.dbpedia.spotlight.candidateMap.dir = /fastdata/spotlight/3.7/candidateIndexTitRedDis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickstart comes with tiny versions of index and spotter.dict.

If you want the same results as our demo webserver, you need to download the larger files with several gigabytes.

You can either overwrite your index and spotter.dict, our change the config to point to the new files.

See http://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Hey Pablo, is it possible instead of getting the output in html format to get it in a Json format or whatever, I mean without forking the git repository.

Comment: Yes, via content negotiation: https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Web-service